# Transform array to key-value array without iteration

Tags: php

What is the easiest way to map array of objects to key-value array of objects, where key is some property of an object?

For example:

```
class Cartoon
{
  public $title;
  public function __construct($title)
  {
    $this->title = $title;
  }
}

$cartoons = array(new Cartoon('Tom and Jerry'), new Cartoon('Cheburashka'));

$mappedCartoons = array();

foreach ($cartoons as $cartoon)
{
  $mappedCartoons[$cartoon->title] = $cartoon;
}

print_r ($mappedCartoons);
```

PS. I wonder if iteration and the extra variable `$mappedCartoons` can be disposed of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `array_reduce` to achive your goal.

```
<?php

$cartoons = array_reduce($cartoons, function($result, $cartoon) {
  $result[$cartoon->title] = $cartoon;
  return $result;
}, array());

?>
```

the idea is not mine, found here: http://www.danielauener.com/howto-use-array_map-functionality-on-an-associative-array-changing-keys-and-values/

Comment: This is brilliant! Now array_reduce is my second favourite friend after array_map.

Comment: Which, behind the scenes, still involves iteration of course. But nice suggestion nonetheless. +1 And perhaps I've misunderstood OP in this respect, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use basic arrays you can simply type out the keys when creating them:

```
$cartoons = array(
    'Tom and Jerry' => new Cartoon('Tom and Jerry'), 
    'Cheburashka' => new Cartoon('Cheburashka'),
);
```

Alternatively you can create container object that implements various array/iteration related interfaces and can be used as a regular array:

```
class CartoonArray extends ArrayObject {

    public function __construct($input, $flags = 0, $iterator_class = "ArrayIterator") {
        parent::__construct(array(), $flags, $iterator_class);
        // since the original ArrayObject implemented in C and they don't it won't pick up our overriden ossetSet we have to type it out here explicitly
        foreach ($input as $value) {
            $this->offsetSet(null, $value);
        }
    }

    public function offsetSet($index, $value) {
        parent::offsetSet($value->title, $value);
    }
}

$cartoons = new CartoonArray(array(new Cartoon('Tom and Jerry'), new Cartoon('Cheburashka')));
$cartoons[] = new Cartoon('Sesame street');

print $cartoons['Tom and Jerry']->title;
unset($cartoons['Tom and Jerry']);

foreach ($cartoons as $k => $v) {
    print $k."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't intend to use generic classes for collections of objects, native arrays only.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way that doesn't involve iterating. I *can* think of a way of not needing an additional variable though:

```
$cartoons = array(new Cartoon('Tom and Jerry'), new Cartoon('Cheburashka'));
foreach( $cartoons as $key => $cartoon )
{
    $cartoons[ $cartoon->title ] = $cartoon;
    unset( $cartoons[ $key ] );
}

var_dump( $cartoons );
```

However, [the documentation of `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) notes:

> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.

I'm not entirely sure that this applies to my example as well. Maybe someone else can chime in here.

To be safe, perhaps this alternative is more appropriate, as it initiates `$len` with the initial length of `$cartoons`, before iteration:

```
$cartoons = array(new Cartoon('Tom and Jerry'), new Cartoon('Cheburashka'));
for( $i = 0, $len = count( $cartoons ); $i < $len; $i++ )
{
    $cartoon = $cartoons[ $i ];
    $cartoons[ $cartoon->title ] = $cartoon;
    unset( $cartoons[ $i ] );
}

var_dump( $cartoons );
```

This example assumes the initial `$cartoons` has 'proper' sequentially numbered keys, starting at `0`, though.